Roblox Tower Placement System Causes Towers to Jump and Float
I'm designing a tower defense game on Roblox with Roblox Studio and am currently experiencing issues with the placement system. There is a button on the screen with the text Place Unit, which for testing purposes is connected to a single model (a noob dummy). The code is supposed to make the model follow the player's mouse in real time and fire a RemoteEvent when the mouse is clicked, placing the unit model on the server side where the user clicked. However, when dragging the mouse to move the model around, it jumps in place and sometimes floats at the camera, only to snap back down and start floating again. This behavior even occurs when the mouse is still. If I click the screen while the unit is mid-jump or mid-float, it is placed in the air. Here's my LocalScript code:
-- Get unit model from ReplicatedStorage
local unit_name = "Noob"
local unit = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")["Unit Models"][unit_name]:Clone()
unit.Parent = game:GetService("Workspace")

local offset = 5
current_position = CFrame.new()

script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    local Mouse = game:GetService("Players").LocalPlayer:GetMouse()

    local lastMousePosition = Mouse.Hit.Position

    -- Update position function
    local function updateTowerPosition()
        local ray = Ray.new(Mouse.UnitRay.Origin, Mouse.UnitRay.Direction * 1000)
        local hitPart, hitPosition = game.Workspace:FindPartOnRay(ray, game.Workspace.Terrain, false, true)
        if hitPosition then
            current_position = CFrame.new(hitPosition) * CFrame.new(0, offset, 0)
            unit:SetPrimaryPartCFrame(current_position)
        end
    end

    -- Initial tower placement
    updateTowerPosition()

    local render_event
    render_event = game:GetService("RunService").RenderStepped:Connect(function()
        local currentMousePosition = Mouse.Hit.Position
        if currentMousePosition ~= lastMousePosition then
            updateTowerPosition()
            lastMousePosition = currentMousePosition
        end
    end)

    Mouse.Button1Down:Once(function()
        render_event:Disconnect()
        unit:Destroy()
        game.ReplicatedStorage.Place:FireServer(unit_name, current_position)
    end)
end)

And here is my server script code that handles the Place RemoteEvent:
-- Server-side unit placement
game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage").Place.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player: Player, unit_name: string, pos: CFrame) 
    local unit = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")["Unit Models"][unit_name]:Clone()
    unit.Parent = game:GetService("Workspace")
    unit.PrimaryPart.CFrame = pos
    unit.PrimaryPart.Anchored = true
end)

I've attempted to force the tower model to not move while the mouse is still, but it continues to hop and (less frequently) float when moved across certain areas of the screen. I don't see what in the code could be causing a jump motion, as I never use Humanoid.Jump or anything similar. The jumps are rapid and repeated. Any help would be appreciated!
